# How to get a component from an array and change its props in react native?

Tags: react-native

I've created some components in a for loop and push them to an array. **Can i get any component from this array to change its props** -like title ?

```
fields = [];
for (let i = 0; i < assets.fieldNames[assets.systemLang].length; i++) {
    fields.push(
           <InfoField
                handlePress={() => this.fieldPressed(i)}
                key={i}
                title={assets.fieldNames[assets.systemLang][i]}
                value="" />
            );
        };

.....
<View style={styles.infoFields}>
  {
     fields
  }
 </View>
```

and i have a function that i need something like this

```
changeComponentTitle = () => {

     fields[indexForComponent].props.title = "new Title"

}
```

Comment: You can change, but you have to declare `fields` variable as a state variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that you trigger a re-render in some way after you make the update (perhaps by putting `fields` in a state variable and calling `setState` as mentioned in the comments) but you can use `cloneElement` to essentially update a single prop of an existing element: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

```
changeComponentTitle = () => {

     fields[indexForComponent] = React.cloneElement(fields[indexForComponent], {title: "new Title"});

}
```

Comment: Could you please test your code, because i couldnt make it.

Comment: Here's a simplified example of using `cloneElement` to do something similar to what you're asking: https://codesandbox.io/embed/admiring-ives-ci04t - notice that the cloned elements after clicking and updating the title prop retain their other original props like the click handler.